# My GUI brings up two windows every time that it starts up

Tags: java, eclipse, multithreading, user-interface

I have a GUI and I every time I click the run button it opens up two of the GUI window! I have no idea why its doing that!
Here is my code:

```
package com.robot;

import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.Toolkit;
import javax.swing.*;

public class GUI extends JFrame implements Runnable {

//start of the constructor method for GUI
public GUI() {

    //defines objects
    Toolkit tk = Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit();
    Dimension dim = tk.getScreenSize();

    //sets the GUI to be visible
    this.setVisible(true);

    //sets the size of the GUI
    this.setSize(600, 400);

    //centers the GUI
    int xPos = (dim.width / 2) - (this.getWidth() /2);
    int yPos = (dim.height / 2) - (this.getHeight() /2);

    this.setLocation(xPos, yPos);

    //makes the program unable to be resized
    this.setResizable(false);

}

public void run() {
    new GUI();
}

}
```

Thanks in advance for helping!

Here is the part that is starting the GUI

```
//main method start
public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException, IOException, AWTException {

    //opens up the GUI
    (new Thread(new GUI())).start();

    //possible methods
    //ScanMarket.scanMarket(); //scans market for data
    //FindPattern("Images"); //finds pattern among images in image folder labeled Images

}//end of main method
```

I'm also wondering how to give my program a title that isn't on the JFrame. On the top left of the screen it says the program is "com.robot.Main" and I want to name it just "ROBOT" but I don't know how to.

Comment: Please show the `main` method, or whatever method is invoking the `GUI` code.

Comment: I just added the main method that launches the GUI

Comment: You've just violated the single thread rules of Swing.  All UI creation and modification is expected to be executed from within the context of the EDT.  Instead of using `new Thread`, you should be using `EventQueue.invokeLater(Runnable)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
(new Thread(new GUI())).start();
```

There and here

```
public void run() {
    new GUI();
}
```

You create two instances of the `GUI` class, which in turn creates two frames. I'd remove the second creation, which is inside the `run()` method to better fix this.

Comment: Thanks! I have one more question though. I'm also wondering how to give my program a title that isn't on the JFrame. On the top left of the screen it says the program is "com.robot.Main" and I want to name it just "ROBOT" but I don't know how to.

Comment: On which screen does it say `com.robot.Main`? On the IDE?

Comment: It doesn't say it on the program screen. I'm on a mac so on the top left of my computer screen right next to the apple symbol it say "com.robot.Main", just like if I were to open up Chrome it would say "Chrome". I want it to say "ROBOT".

Comment: @leonardude that is a native Java feature on OSX. AFAIK, there is no way to change that using just Java.

Comment: Its not a native thing to OSX. If you are on a windows it appears right next to (well actually to the left of) what would be the "File", "Edit", "View", etc tabs on a program such as Chrome if you opened up Chrome.